# Redirect [dragonrider] to [dragon-v2]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The official name of SpaceX's first manned capsule is [dragon-v2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-v2) so why not unify that on tag instead of double-tagging with [dragonrider](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonrider)?

I agree that the code name is comparatively nice — especially considering that "V-2" was a WWII terror weapon and "Crew Dragon," which SpaceX also seems to occasionally use, sounds like "Crude Dragon."

However, the official name is official, for a year now, and it's not likely to ever change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done the merge as suggested, and also merged [dragon2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon2) to the same. It seems many questions were tagged with two or three of those tags, and they all are essentially the same.

Comment: Is a redirect different than a synonym or merging?

Comment: I merged them, it's not any different.