# Should [dragon-v2] and [crew-dragon] be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

SpaceX [really likes to rename things](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/rename-the-bfr-tag) and the crewed Dragon capsule is no exception

The problem is we have [dragon-v2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-v2)

> SpaceX's second version of the Dragon spacecraft, also called "Crew Dragon". It is designed to carry humans.

And [crew-dragon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crew-dragon) (no excerpt)

[dragon-v2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-v2) has [been renamed once before](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/redirect-dragonrider-to-dragon-v2)

Since "Crew Dragon" seems to [the official name now](https://www.spacex.com/dragon) we probably should retag the [crew-dragon] stuff and then rename [dragon-v2] to [crew-dragon]

Comment: I have heard rumors of cargo versions of the Dragon 2 (which would still autonomously dock to an IDA) further down the line, though I don't know if they solidified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see evidence at that link that Crew Dragon is the only official name of Dragon 2, and I still see other recent SpaceX pages using "Dragon 2". The way the community had been using the two different tags was that [crew-dragon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crew-dragon) was for questions regarding the spacecraft's intended use as a human spaceflight craft, whereas [dragon-v2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-v2) was inclusive of its use as a cargo-only spacecraft.

---

My proposed band-aid in the comments:

> Hmm..well, there are only seven questions on crew-dragon. Maybe I should just move those over to dragon-v2 and make the synonym that direction for now. Then if SpaceX does stop using "Dragon 2", we can swap things over to crew-dragon as the primary.

Comment: I'm not so sure. [This SpaceX page from 2014](https://www.spacex.com/news/2014/05/30/dragon-v2-spacexs-next-generation-manned-spacecraft) seems to indicate it's talking about Crew Dragon. [Wikipedia thinks the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_2)

Comment: I agree the names are interchangeable as far as SpaceX is concerned, but I don't see any evidence they have stopped using Dragon 2 so I don't know that it should affect our community use of the tags yet.

Comment: Would a mere synonym be in order then? The two tags are prone to confusion

Comment: @Machavity Hmm..well, there are only seven questions on [tag:crew-dragon]. Maybe I should just move those over to [tag:dragon-v2] and make the synonym that direction for now. Then if SpaceX does stop using "Dragon 2", we can swap things over to [tag:crew-dragon] as the primary.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me

Comment: @Machavity Done.